# Is there a way I can reduce the number of digits after the decimal point?

Tags: gps, coordinates

I am having a little trouble with my android application. I want to display the current latitude and longitude using the GPS of the phone. I am able to get the current coordinates of the phone but it is displayed as a double value with ... I think 6 - 8 digits after the decimal point. Is there a way I can reduce the number of digits after the decimal point?

Here is the code I have:

```
public class Localisation extends Activity implements LocationListener{

protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
protected Context context;
private String TripDescription;
private String tripID;



TextView txtLat;
String lat;
String provider;
protected String latitude, longitude;

protected boolean gps_enabled, network_enabled;


@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_localisation);
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    Log.d("Latitude","disable");

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude","enable");     
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d("Latitude","status");     
}
```

Comment: Consider an upvote for my answer, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce (a float or double) to 6 digits:

```
double oldVal = location.getLatitude();
double newVal = ((int) Math.round(oldVal * 1E6)) / 1E6;
```

The multiplication with one million truncates everything after the 6 digit.
After dividing back, the value is limited to 6 digits.

Comment: Works here. Thank you.